# Reload Xaml Page from Hyperlinkbutton

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, hyperlink

How can I use a Hyperlinkbutton in Xaml to reload my Xaml Page? How must I set the NavigateUri Property to reload the page?

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="Reload Page" NavigateUri="" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="Reload Page" NavigateUri="Page.xaml" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
```

Comment: if i do this and click the link there comes a message to search for an app in the app store. don't work.

Comment: try this then NavigateUri="/Directory/PageName.xaml"

Comment: the PageName.xaml is in the main directory and the /PageName.xaml also don't work